# how to remove cdk-table-exporter from package.lock.json

Tags: angular

I'm trying to remove the cdk-table-exporter.js depends on warning.  I am using mat-table-exporter and I think I installed cdk-table-exporter by mistake awhile back.  I have npm uninstalled cdk-table-exporter and reinstalled mat-table-exporter and several combinations, but it continues to reside on package.lock.json, which "seems" to be producing the warning.  I'm on angular/cli 12.1.1, so I don't think I'm trying to deal with any previous version issues - Anyone know how to get rid of it?

Comment: remove "cdk-table-exporter" from package.json  also delete package.lock.json delete node_modules and install npm again

Comment: I see, so basically reinstall -  ok thanks